# locking content with overlay/pop up ads

Tags: functions

how can i add a pop up before content or before downloading files ?i want to show a custom ad pop up (with option to close ad-similar to what you see in ad.fly url shortener) before a file download /and/or page access . Tried looking in plugins but all of them seem to be old and not updated lately..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [Popup Builder](https://wordpress.org/plugins/popup-builder/) plugin? It was being updated 3 days ago. It should work for you.

Comment: just installed it..looks like i can work it that,has the functions i need and its updated. Tank you !

Comment: You are welcome. Please, choose it as the right answer.